# Emitting different value class than the one declared [MapReduce]

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am using Jimmy Lin's Github repo [[1](https://github.com/lintool/tools/blob/master/lintools-datatypes/src/main/java/tl/lin/data/array/ArrayListOfDoublesWritable.java)] in my project. However it came to my attention that the ArrayListOfDoublesWritable is returning DoubleWritable. This is not a problem if I'm using it in the Reduce phase, i.e:

```
public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text,DoubleWritable,Text,ArrayListOfDoublesWritable>
```

The reason being that I could set the parameter of method *setOutputValueClass* to *DoubleWritable.class*.

But this does not seem to be the case when I am using it in the Map phase. Hadoop is complaining that it is expecting DoubleWritable while actually receiving ArrayListOfDoublesWritable.

Is there any way to set the Map Value Class to be different than the one declared? I have gone through the method *setMapOutputValueClass* but that did not seem to be the fix for this problem.

--Driver--

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration(); 
String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs(); // get all args
if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
  System.err.println("Usage: WordCount <in> <out>");
  System.exit(2);
}


Job job = new Job(conf, "job 1");
job.setJarByClass(Kira.class);

job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

// set output key type   
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
// set output value type
job.setOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);

//set the HDFS path of the input data
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
// set the HDFS path for the output
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));

//Wait till job completion
System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

Notice my output value class is set to DoubleWritable.class although I have declared ArrayListOfDoublesWritable.

How can possibly do this for the Mapper?

Comment: if map output value and reduce output value are different, you should declare both. Do you do that? Can you post the Driver/main?

Comment: and it still doesn't work when you add (not replacing any other line) the command setMapOutputValueClass (and perhaps setMapOutputKeyClass)?

Comment: yes it still doesn't work. I have read through the method and I think it only works if you want to explicitly set the MapOutput class that you ALREADY HAVE. For instance, if your map job IS SUCCESSFUL and it gave you a DoubleWritable (with this being said, you have declared in the Mapper code <DoubleWritable>), but you want to change it to something other than DoubleWritable. But in my case, the Mapper job is not yet successful.

Comment: or can you suggest any ready implementation of array list in mapreduce?